# Not able to Change String (innerHtml) to Number with Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, innerhtml, parseint, parsefloat

I am not able to change string from innerHTML to number with javascript, the innerHTML of the element is like 1.2.34, I have tried ParseFloat, ParseInt and Number functions, they are working but only for the string(innerHTML) which is in the form of 1.23 means having only one decimal point, but in my case I have more than 1, 2 decimals and not able to change them in js. PLEASE help me fix this problem.

Comment: Is this a semver (version number)? If so, there are [JavaScript libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=semver) designed to deal with these.

Comment: actually, it is just an input you can say, I am getting it from an element on-page, it isn't version number

Comment: is the purpose that you can then add time to the number? Can you give a use case of how you use this innerHTML?

Comment: I am using this innerHTML to calculate the average of different times, it is working with numbers like 1.23 but I have my innerHTML like 1.2.34

Comment: So your format is `HH.MM.SS` (hours, minutes, seconds)? Are you wanting to convert that into decimal hours (e.g 1.30.36 = 1.51 hours)?

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat, parseInt can be applied only for the text or number having proper decimal format. ex : 100,1.24,100.24,100.254 but you are trying with 1.2.4 which is not a valid decimal formats, when you try to parse this invalid format with int or float, the JS will consider as invalid arguments for the parseInt or parseFloat.

So i am considering the innerHtml as hh.mm.ss paster the code snippet as below

```
var time = '1.24.3';   // input string from innerHtml
var timearray = time.split('.'); // split it with .

// You can multiply hours to seconds or minutes
var totalminutes = (+timearray[0]) * 60 + (+timearray[1]);

//then you can add the every time and divide by n
-->You logic goes here
```

Comment: ok thank you, but is there any way I can get my result change number to string like this?

Comment: Can you explain in specific that what is your input and expected output ?

Comment: I am coding a stopwatch timer, so the innerHTML i am getting is in the form of something 1.2.4 and I want to use it to get the average and for that I need to convert it into number first

Comment: @Nimish as your input was not much clear to me,  i have modified the above answer section with code snippet, hope it will help you.